# I went too far back in my KSP world

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Can someone help me? I'm having a panic attack because I failed a Kerbal Space Program mission. I pressed <kbd>F9</kbd> and went back really far in the game, and, like, 3 things unlocked in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

There's a rolling backup of the persistant save in your KSP save folder

```
<KSP Folder>\saves\<World save>\Backup
```

Take one by one back into the parent folder and call them with the Alt+F9 key.

When you found the one, do a Alt+F5 to put a big checkpoint in your main game, the `persistent.sfs` which contains the current game will automatically be overwritten.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the help but i got to my ksp file then saves then my world then it showed as you said persistent.sfs then two other stuff kinda confused could you please explain from there but explain it like your doing it to a monkey